# jQuery get index of clicked element using the $.on event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen ways of getting the index of an element clicked on by using the following code:

```
$('.element').mouseup(function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
});
```

However due to the way in which my elements are dynamically generated I have to attach my event handler as so:

```
$(document).on("mouseup", ".element", function(){
    //Do things 
});
```

Since `$(this)` will simply return the document, how can I find the index of the element that the event was triggered on?

Comment: `$('.element')` returns an array of elements, and index is the index into that array.  in your context, index has no meaning.  what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There are multiple elements with the class that triggers the mouseup event on the page. I need the index so I can later use ```$(".element).eq(n)```, so I can apply changes to the specific element that triggered the event.

Comment: what's wrong this using `$(this)` which also returns the element?  sounds like you're trying to do this the hard way.  if elements are dynamically generated, the index may change, etc.

Comment: If you want a simpler way to use a mouse click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually mistaken `$(this)` called within the scope of ```$(document).on("mouseup", ".element", function(){...}); does actually return the element that triggers this event.

This means my question is pointless, but I'll leave it up for historical purposes if anyone else has the same mistaken question.

Comment: i would suggest taking the question down.  it doesn't really make sense.  more likely it will confuse people.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to grab the parent, select the children via:

```
let index = $(this).parent().children();
```

Then, use this to grab the index:

```
index.index(this);
```

So to wrap it all together, though I don't know why the index is relevant here..

```
$(document).on("mouseup", ".element", function(){
    let index = $(this).parent().children();
    index = index.index(this);
});
```

Here's a runnable version for you

One way is to grab the parent, select the children via:

```
let index = $(this).parent().children();
```

Then, use this to grab the index:

```
index.index(this);
```

So to wrap it all together, though I don't know why the index is relevant here..

```js
$(document).on("mouseup", ".element", function(){
    let index = $(this).parent().children();
    index = index.index(this);
    console.log(index)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">test 0</div>
<div class="element">test 1</div>
<div class="element">test 2</div>
<div class="element">test 3</div>
<div class="element">test 4</div>
<div class="element">test 5</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, but sadly I am mistaken, using $(this) within the on event handler does actually return the element that triggered the event.

Your answer wouldn't work if this weren't the case, since you'd be trying to retrieve the parent of the document, which is nonexistant.

Comment: It does yes, but is does not return the index. I guess i misunderstood the question

Comment: No, it would return the parent of `$(this)` which is the element you clicked on

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <ul class="element">
        <li >one</li>
        <li >two</li>
        <li >three</li>
        <li >four</li>
        <li >five</li>
        <li >six</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        $(document).on("mouseup", ".element", function (e) {
            //Do things 
            //var index = $(this).index();
            console.log($(e.target).index());
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

For such html, all you need to do is to include event object in the call back.
As shown above, it prints the indices on the console window.